# How to check the format of time input in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, time

I've a `textbox` called `HourTb`. I get the current time from `TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;` In order to make the time in 12-hour format, here's what I've done:

```
        if (currentTime < TimeSpan.Parse("12:00")) //Morning
        {
            if (currentTime.Hours.ToString("00") == "00")
                HourTb.Text = "12";

            else
                HourTb.Text = currentTime.Hours.ToString("00");

            AmOrPmTb.Text = "AM";
        }

        else //Afternoon, night
        {
            HourTb.Text = (currentTime - TimeSpan.Parse("12:00")).Hours.ToString("00"); //12-hour format
            AmOrPmTb.Text = "PM";
        }
```

The problem that I'm facing now is how to check the value input to `HourTb` is a proper value in TextChangedEvent:

- If input > 12 or input = 00 or 0 only, `HourTb.Text = string.Empty;`
- If input is single digit (e.g. 9), then `HourTb.Text = "09";`

Comment: First one; If your input is `13` for example, your `else` part will be executed and your `HourTb.Text` should be `01` not empty string. This problem could be somewhere else. Please debug your code and see what happens. Second one; since you _still_ format your `9` with `00` format, it will has a leading zero `09` as you have. That's normal.

Answer (score 0):

For getting time in 12 hour format you can use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

For getting time in 24 hour format you can use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")
```

`hh` will give you the hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

`HH` will give you the hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

Comment: OP doesn't have _any_ `DateTime` in the code part. It has `TimeSpan`s. Sure `DateTime.Now` can be used based on `currentTime` calculation.

Comment: Yes I am telling for the calculation of `currentTime` only.

Comment: Hi @AayushiJain, thanks for your reply, but what I want is the checking part when user input hour value in the textbox